# LEFT JOIN / WHERE clause with is null and false Estimated Number Of Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

I have a table named `Product` and a table named `ProductPropertiesCountry`.

`Product` is the definition of a product (description, price, productId, etc)

`ProductPropertiesCountry` contains restrictions on the product by country, for example `IsBlocked`, and attributes such as `Special Price`.

```
Product
 - ProductId
 - Description
 - Price

ProductPropertiesCountry
 - ProductId (PK)
 - CountryId (PK)
 - SpecialPrice
 - IsBlocked
```

I'm doing a `LEFT JOIN` between `Product` and `ProductPropertiesCountry` with a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT P.ProductId
FROM Product P
    LEFT JOIN ProductPropertiesCountry PPC ON 
        P.ProductId = PPC.Product AND PPC.CountryID = 1
WHERE (IsBlocked IS NULL OR IsBlocked = 0)
```

The problem is that the execution plan does not handle `IsBlocked IS NULL` efficiently and it gives me `Estimated number of rows = 1` after that filter.  As result, the query is slower.

This is much faster:

```
;WITH CATALOG
AS 
(
   SELECT P.ProductId, ISNULL(IsBlocked, 0) AS IsBlocked
    FROM Product P
        LEFT JOIN ProductPropertiesCountry PPC 
            ON P.ProductId = PPC.Product AND PPC.CountryID = 1
)
SELECT ProductId, IsBlocked
FROM CATALOG
WHERE IsBlocked = 0;
```

Do you have any idea for the reason of this behavior?

Any suggestion to change it to get the right estimated number of rows in execution plan?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Do you have to use left outer join, why not an inner join since both the tables share the same productid (pk) , and i think you can try replacing this `WHERE (IsBlocked IS NULL OR IsBlocked = 0)` with this `Where isnull(IsBlocked,0) = 0`

Comment: I did try that, same result. Yes, I need to do a left join, because the product can have no properties for an specific country.

Comment: IsBlocked is not nullable. If I do the left join like that I would have the IsBlocked nullable for those items that are blocked or without any property on that country. Right?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I'm assuming you meant removing the `IsBlocked = 0` condition from `WHERE` and leaving the `WHERE IS NULL` part only. (After all, we are dealing with a *left* join.) That would still result in a different output. Presently, the queries retrieve Products that have no match in PPC or those that have `PPC.IsBlocked = 0`. With your suggestion, the results would contain Products that are absent from `PPC` or have `PPC.IsBlocked` other than `0`. However, `ON P.ProductId = PPC.Product AND PPC.CountryID = 1 AND PPC.IsBlocked = 1` and leaving the `WHERE IS NULL` check should do the trick.

Comment: @AndriyM, leaving WHERE IS NULL and IsBlocked=1 will not give me the information I need from ProductPropertiesCountry. Like SpecialPrice for example.

Comment: @AndriyM - Agreed my suggestion would change the semantics. Will delete!

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to pull a value from PPC, you can't do a proper Semi / AntiSemi Join. If you put a unique index on PPC (CountryID, Product) INCLUDE (IsBlocked, SpecialPrice), you should get a better cardinality estimate, as it'll either be there or not, and the multi-column statistics from this index will give a better answer.

Comment: I already did that. Still not working as good as it should.